# Resolve Attribute Error - Can I do this by defining variable?

Tags: python, variables, attributeerror

I am new to Python and am wondering how to address the following attribute error. I believe I need to define/declare the file variable? Thanks for any suggestions, here is my script:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
     51 
     52     # Write methods to print to Financial_Analysis_Summary
---> 53     file.write("Financial Analysis")
     54     file.write("\n")
     55     file.write("----------------------------")
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 0):

From your code and error, I think You've defined the variable 'file' as a string. Aslo there is no attribute write() in the class str. Hence, the reason for this error. For more information, include the whole script i.e., mainly the use of variable 'file'. I think you can use print() to print the above mentioned details or create a new class with a method inside to print your desired things

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've somehow defined `file` as a string rather than a file. What you should to is define it thus:

```
summary_file=open("C:/someFolder/someOtherFolder/Financial_Analysis_Summary.txt",
        mode='r+', encoding='utf8')
```

and then write to it.
The first argument to the `open` function is the file path. The `mode` is how you want to access the file: `'r'` lets you read the file and nothing else (and throws a `FileNotFoundError` if the file doesn't yet exist; the others just create it), `'r+'` lets you write to the file while leaving its preexisting text in place (although if you write to the middle of the file you'll still overwrite whatever was there), `'w'` deletes what was in the file and lets you write to it, `'a'` lets you write text only to the end of the file, `'w+'` and `'a+'` are the same as `w` and `a` except they let you read from the file; you can add `b` to the end of any of these to interact with the file in the form of bytes rather than strings. The `encoding` should only matter if you plan to use Unicode characters, in which case set it to the same encoding you'll use to view the file (usually `'utf8'`) to avoid garbling non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer